# Rails Stimulus two data targets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, stimulusjs

so im experimenting and learning Rails Stimulus and the idea i want to realise is that i have two modal forms ( one for login and second for registration ) my view:

```
<div data-controller="modal">

  <button data-action="click->modal#login" data-target="loginForm" class="flex items-center">
   Login
  </button>

  <div data-modal-target="loginForm" class="relative z-10 hidden">
    <%= render 'layouts/modal_login' %>
  </div>

  <div data-modal-target="registerForm" class="relative z-10 hidden">
    <%= render 'layouts/modal_register' %>
  </div>

</div>
```

and inside login and register partials i want to add button to switch between modal forms
example from modal_login:

```
<button data-action="click->modal#register" class="flex items-center">
  Register
</button>
```

and my stimulus modal_controller.js:

```
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['loginForm', 'registerForm'];

  login() {
    console.log("login");
    this.loginFormTarget.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }

  register() {
    console.log("register");
    this.loginFormTarget.classList.toggle('hidden');
    this.registerFormTarget.classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
}
```

Question

1. is this even a good approach ?
2. why when i try to call data-action register from login partial i get:

```
Error invoking action "click->modal#register"

Error: Missing target element "registerForm" for "modal" controller
```

i expected that when i press register button the login modal will hide and register modal form will be displayed

Comment: Does "console.log("register");" get invoked? Do you see some output in the console? Gotn the loginForm hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your approach should work. I'd suggest the following:

```
<button data-action="click->modal#login" data-target="loginForm" class="flex items-center">
   Login
</button>
```

--> You should omit "data-target="loginForm"". I guess it's a missunderstanding. Data-Target ist not the target of the action (you want to toggle the loginForm), but simply an identifier of the element (in this case the button).

Perhaps you have a second registerForm-Target in on of your partials - please check and delete, too.

Secondly you should add a parameter to your JS-Methods like this:

```
login(event) {
   ...   
}

register(event) {
    ...
}
```

For the start I recommend to add a connect-Method to make sure that your controller is loading correctly:

```
connect(){
  console.log("Controller connected")
}
```